# Swagger download link not showing

Tags: angular, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to get this type of download link for the swaggers like the petstore.json gives -

[image]

Link to the petstore swagger - https://petstore.swagger.io/

I am using swagger-ui-dist in angular with the following configuration to render the swaggers -

```
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
          dom_id: '#swagger-dist',
          layout: 'BaseLayout',
          presets: [SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis, SwaggerUIBundle.SwaggerUIStandalonePreset],
          plugins: [SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl],
          spec: response,
          docExpansion: 'none'
        });
```

But for some reason, the download link is not coming up for me.

My swagger-ui-dist version is - 3.25.2

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: swagger is created on your backend not in angular. show us your backend configurations

Comment: I am getting the swaggers stored in a S3 bucket and then have to render them on the UI

Answer (score 1):

Swagger UI displays the download link only if the API definition is loaded from a URL, e.g.:

```js
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  dom_id: '#swagger-dist',
  url: 'https://example.com/myapi.yaml',   // <----
  ...
});
```

The link is NOT displayed when the `spec` parameter is used, such as in your example:

```js
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  dom_id: '#swagger-dist',
  spec: response,   // <-----
  ...
});
```

In this case the contents of the API definition is provided as a JavaScript object and it doesn't have a URL.